# Visual Studio, ASP.NET 5 and the IApplicationBuilder interface

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When developing ASP.NET 5 application I often get into the trouble of not knowing the names of the extension methods available on the IApplicationBuilder interface.

(This may sound really stupid). I was in my `Startup.cs` file and I wanted to add MVC. I only found (let's say my IApplicationBuilder instance is called `app`) `app.UseMvcCore();`. What I really wanted was `app.UseMvc();`. They are (or were) in different packages. This is a pretty dumb example, but you get the idea. If I don't know an extension method called `app.RunIISPipeline();`, how would I know it is available? I think this should be shown in IntelliSense.

Why doesn't Visual Studio give suggestions on available extension methods on packages that's in the configured NuGet feed in addition to installed packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree in that it's a little more difficult compared to prior (closed source) versions of ASP.NET when your machine already had everything installed, especially with dnxcore50.

It would be difficult to show this in intellisense for packages that are not installed considering how many packages are on nuget, and considering the chance for naming conflicts, how would nuget determine which package you want just by a (partial) method name within that package?

A workaround is to take a quick look at the package you want on github.  For example, if you know you want to add `Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc`, go to [github.com/aspnet/mvc](http://github.com/aspnet/mvc), hit <kbd>T</kbd>, and type `extensions` or even better, `applicationbuilderextensions`.  You'll then see extensions that are defined.

**Update**

You could additionally search within a repository's files for the occurrence of `this IApplicationBuilder` to find the extension methods using the following search string in the github repository's search box;

```
"this IApplicationBuilder" in:file
```

[Example](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22this+IApplicationBuilder%22+in%3Afile&type=Code).

Comment: I guess you could determine the key as NuGet package ID + method name, but there would be alot of suggestions, I agree. Thanks for the GitHub example. That was really helpful. However, if we don't know where the extensions are defined (in other words: in what package), then we are at stuck at the same issue. I guess I need to always do a search at packages I find at GitHub after `applicationbuilderextensions`. By the way, is this the naming convention? Developers who write libraries are free to give it another name if the want, since this is only an extension method?

Comment: Nuget just delivers the package you specify - it doesn't help you determine which package you need for a specific function.  Developers can call the extension methods whatever they want.  In [Identity](github.com/aspnet/Identity) it's called [BuilderExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/BuilderExtensions.cs) - which is probably the more common name for it that I've seen.  Documentation is what is key here - it helps you find (google) the package you need, and how to configure it.  Because ASP.NET is so new, documentation is limited.

Comment: Yes, it seems like everyone names them different. It would be nice if it were possible to search inside the source code files on GitHub. Then you could search for `this IAppBuilder`. At least that would point out where they are!